# Scheme- Largest difference between two lists

Tags: scheme

Given two lists of numbers (of the same length), return the largest difference between corresponding pairs of numbers (without creating another list).  For example...

```
Given [ 2 6 3 ] and [ 4 6 2 ],
their differences are [ (2-4) (6-6) (3-2) ], or [ 2 0 1 ],
so the largest difference is 2.
```

Notice that difference is always positive (the absolute value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I only provide code when OP provide code so here is the solution just described. Happy coding!*

You can use `fold-left` and supply a procedure that takes the maximum of accumulator and the absolute of the difference between the two elements being processed.

`fold-left` is the [R6RS name](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_212) and resides in the library `(rnrs lists (6))`. For a compatible approach you'll need to use [SRFI-1 List Library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html). Here it's called [`fold`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap) and the accumulator is the last argument instead of the first.

Many R5RS Scheme implementations and Languages that are derived from a Scheme language (like Racket) has a left fold implemented by the name `foldl`. You need to check it's documentation to get the argument order as they vary. It's not a part of the standard so it's not portable between implementations. I urge you to either use R6RS or SRFI-1.